# Add preprocessor definitions to FetchContent in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, c-preprocessor

I'm using CMake to compile my C++ project and I have dependency, which is downloaded using `FetchContent`, but by default, that dependency is using exceptions, that are disabled in my project and so I have to pass preprocessor definition to this dependency to disable them. This is what I do:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
  sioclient
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp.git
  GIT_TAG        3.1.0
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(sioclient)

add_compile_definitions("_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS_")
```

Looks like CMake passes `add_compile_definitions` into anything in my project, but not into dependency. How can I set preprocessor definitions for dependencies downloaded and populated by `FetchContent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams to work when `add_compile_definitions(_WEBSOCKETPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS_)` is added before the FetchContent stuff.

Or alternatively, it works with a target specific definition:
`target_compile_definitions(sioclient PUBLIC _WEBSOCKETPP_NO_EXCEPTIONS_)`

Comment: The alternative will complain "Cannot specify compile definitions for target xxx which is not built by this project."